PySpark: How To Deserialise A Proto Payload From A Kafka Message With Variable Message Type
I am trying to read from a Kafka topic that contains messages with different Proto payloads. With the messageName set in the Kafka message key.
But when I try to:
df = spark.readStream.format(constants.KAFKA_INPUT_FORMAT) \
        .options(**options) \
        .load()
df = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)").alias('key')
df = df.select(from_protobuf('value', df.key, desc_file_path).alias('value'))

I get the pyspark.errors.exceptions.base.PySparkTypeError: [NOT_ITERABLE] Column is not iterable error.
How can I dynamically set the messageName parameter of the from_protobuf function with the key value of the Kafka message attribute?

step 1 is extract Kafka Key/Value(s): easy I leave it for you
step 2 is to define a function for dynamic Protobuf deserialization
from google.protobuf import descriptor_pool, message_factory
from google.protobuf.descriptor_pb2 import FileDescriptorSet

def deserialize_protobuf(message_name, serialized_payload, descriptor_file):
    with open(descriptor_file, "rb") as f:
        file_descriptor_set = FileDescriptorSet.FromString(f.read())

    pool = descriptor_pool.DescriptorPool()
    for file_descriptor_proto in file_descriptor_set.file:
        pool.Add(file_descriptor_proto)

    message_descriptor = pool.FindMessageTypeByName(message_name)
    if not message_descriptor:
        raise ValueError(f"Message type {message_name} not found in descriptor.")

    message_class = message_factory.MessageFactory(pool).GetPrototype(message_descriptor)
    message = message_class.FromString(serialized_payload)

    return message

step 3: Use foreachBatch for dynamic deserialization
def process_batch(batch_df, batch_id):
    from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
    from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

    @pandas_udf(StringType())
    def protobuf_deserializer(message_names, payloads):
        results = []
        for message_name, payload in zip(message_names, payloads):
            try:
                # Deserialize using the function above
                message = deserialize_protobuf(
                    message_name=message_name,
                    serialized_payload=payload,
                    descriptor_file="path/to/descriptor/file"
                )
                results.append(message.SerializeToString())
            except Exception as e:
                results.append(None)
        return pd.Series(results)

    deserialized_df = batch_df.withColumn(
        "deserialized_value",
        protobuf_deserializer(col("messageName"), col("value"))
    )

    deserialized_df.write.format("parquet").mode("append").save("/path/to/output")

query = df.writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(process_batch) \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()

good luck

Hey Ali, yes that is the way I end up following. Thanks.
